# C++: Do I need "if" statement for destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

I think my destructor of Vector class below should have `if` statement to cancel the memory that it uses. If `arr` has one member, it will have `delete arr`. And if `arr` has many members, I must use `delete[] arr`.

*Could you tell me that is necessary?*

My code:

```
class Vector {
    double * arr;
    short dim;

public:
    Vector(short d = 0): dim(d) {
        arr = NULL;
        if (dim < 0) {
            dim = 0;
        } else {
            arr = new double[dim];
        }
    }

    ~Vector() {
        if (arr != NULL) {
            if (dim == 1) {
                delete arr;
            } else {
                delete[] arr;
            }

            arr = NULL;
            dim = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: "If `arr` has one member, it will have `delete arr`" What makes you think that?

Comment: Unrelated, I see no reason whatsoever for the `dim` member of this, nor the construction parameter provided to initialize it, to be *signed*. For matters such as this, `std::size_t` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Setting `arr` to `NULL` and `dim` to `0` at the end of the destructor is pointless, since the object is going away. Nobody will ever see those values. And the test for `NULL` isn't needed, so the destructor body can be much simpler: `~vector() { delete [] arr; }`.

Comment: Where's your copy constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not only it's not necessary, it is just incorrect. Anything that was created with `new []` can only be deleted with `delete []`. Otherwise it creates an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Not only is this not necessary but this is illegal since you only allocate memory with `new[]`.  If you call `new` you need a `delete`, if you call `new[]` you need a call to `delete[]`.  Mixing them is undefined behavior.  Your vector it should look something like:

```
class Vector {
    double * arr;
    short dim;

public:
    Vector(short d = 0): dim(d) {
        if (dim > 0)
            arr = new double[dim]
        else
            arr = nullptr;
    }

    Vector(const Vector& copy) : dim(copy.dim) {
        if (dim > 0) {
            arr = new double[dim]
            // copy data here
        }
        else
            arr = nullptr;
    }

    ~Vector() {
        delete [] arr;
    }

    Vector & operator=(Vector rhs) {
        // swap the contents of the copy.  you can make a swap function to do this
        double * temp = arr;
        arr = rhs.arr;
        rhs.arr = temp;
        dim = rhs.dim;
    }

};
```

Now we have correct copies and delete will either be a non-op on a `nullptr` or correctly deallocate the memory allocated from the constructor.

Comment: IMO, if you provided a copy constructor, there should also be a copy assignment operator.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good suggestion.  I just left it out to show the constructors.  I added a basic example.

Answer (score 4):

You never call `new double;` anywhere, so it's not needed. Always call `delete [] arr;`. Check for `NULL` isn't needed also.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not necessary. Make sure when you create allocated memory using new keyword to delete the memory without square brackets avoid mixing them.